# Combine 2 NSURL sessions so I can combine two of these instagram users photos together

Tags: ios, instagram, nsurl

As you can see I have two methods `tuula` and `wendyslookbook`. Then I call them both in my `mostPopular` method. I have requested the photos from the Instagram API but now I want to put these two user photos together. How can I do that?

```
//
//  PhotosViewController.m
//  Photo Bombers
//
//  Created by Alex Macleod on 20/8/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Alex Macleod. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PhotosViewController.h"
#import "PhotoCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "PresentDetailTransition.h"
#import "DismissDetailTransition.h"

#import <SimpleAuth/SimpleAuth.h>

@interface PhotosViewController () <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) NSString *accessToken;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *photos;
@end

@implementation PhotosViewController

- (instancetype) init {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(106.0, 106.0);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0;

    return (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Fashun";

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[PhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photo"];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.accessToken = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];

    if (self.accessToken == nil) {

        [SimpleAuth authorize:@"instagram" options:@{@"scope": @[@"likes"]} completion:^(NSDictionary *responseObject, NSError *error) {

             self.accessToken = responseObject[@"credentials"][@"token"];
            [userDefaults setObject:self.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
            [userDefaults synchronize];

            [self mostPopular];
        }];
    } else {
        [self mostPopular];
    }
}

- (void)tuula {
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/7522782/media/recent/?access_token=%@", self.accessToken];


    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"links: %@", location);

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:location];
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        self.photos = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });
    }];
    [task resume];

}

- (void)wendyslookbook {
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/14454619/media/recent/?access_token=%@", self.accessToken];


    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"links: %@", location);

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:location];
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        self.photos = [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });
    }];
    [task resume];

}


- (void)mostPopular {
    [self tuula];
    [self wendyslookbook];

}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.photos count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photo" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    cell.photo = self.photos[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *photo = self.photos[indexPath.row];
    DetailViewController *viewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    viewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    viewController.photo = photo;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                                  presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                      sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return [[PresentDetailTransition alloc]init];
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    return [[DismissDetailTransition alloc]init];
}


@end
```

Comment: only one user shows at a time its so annoying!

Comment: Download them separately and use whatever imaging technology you are using to combine them.  Why do you think the network sessions need to be combined?  That doesn't make sense.